# geocode_ip_address except specific controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

I have added `geocode_ip_address` in ApplicationController so I can get the user location info from their session.

I have some controllers that I don't want them to be checked against Geokit. It really slows application and there's no need for geo check there.

Since its called like `geocode_ip_address` and not as a `before_filter` I'm not able to use `skip_before_filter`

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it actually uses store_ip_location filter so you can put

```
skip_before_filter :store_ip_location
```

That being said it stores the result of the geo code inside a cookie that is being checked before making a service call so the subsequent calls should not impact performance that much

Answer (score -1):

You can selectively NOT INVOKE the code based on the controller you're in like so:

```
unless ["controller1", "controller2", "etc"].member?(params[:controller])
 geocode_ip_address
end
```

Put the names of the controllers you don't want the code to run for in the list and it won't be invoked in those controllers.

You could also create a constant that's a list of controllers like this:

```
CONTROLLERS_TO_NOT_FILTER_BY_GEOCODE = ["controller1", "controller2", "etc"]

unless CONTROLLERS_TO_NOT_FILTER_BY_GEOCODE.member?(params[:controller])
 geocode_ip_address
end
```

Comment: I don't think that's really effective. I should do the other way around (do not load geocode_ip_address for certain controllers). Other than those controllers, should always go in ApplicationController.

Comment: I was under the impression from @Martin that `skip_before_filter` could not be used -- he indicated specifically so in the question. I'm unsure why it was downvoted. Can someone elaborate if there was an issue with the answer?